# How to use M21 and SVD sniper rifles in BC2: Vietnam?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2-vietnam

Can someone please suggest what is a good strategy and attachments for M21 and SVD rifles as I am really struggling with them. At which range should they be used, where to aim, at which rate to shoot, etc.

If I use it as an assault rifle with 4x scope then at middle-close range any regular rifle would outperform it. If I put 12x scope and snipe with it then the only way to get a kill for me is to find someone dumb enough to stand still while I shoot 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should treat them as [designated marksman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Designated_marksman) rifles and not true sniper rifles. In other words engage at medium range where you have the accuracy advantage but not at the extreme range of a sniper rifle. If the enemy gets too close, withdraw and find a better spot. Look for large stretches of open terrain so you can keep the target in sight to get off follow-up shots to your first shot.  This'll help you actually get kills with them.

Comment: +1 for the interesting link (nice description of difference with snipers)

Comment: Also game mode I found was the easiest to get kills with them was hardcore conquest.